# How to serialize attribute without relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

```
App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
  families: DS.hasMany('family'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  config: DS.attr('string')
});


Product.set('name', 'Mark');
Product.save();
```

The config attribute before save:

```
config:[ { key: color, value: [Array : 2] }, ... ]
```

The config attribute after save:

```
config:[object Object],[object Object]
```

Why???

Comment: How did you setup your serialization?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting `config` to an `Object` if you want it to be a `String`? If you really want to store an object, you’ll have to take care of serialising/deserialising it to/from JSON (or whatever other format). You could use a computed property:

```
config: DS.attr('string'),

configObject: function(key, value, previousValue) {
  // setter
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    this.set('config', JSON.stringify(value));
  }

  // getter
  return JSON.parse(this.get('config'));
}
```